# Screen capture utility for Safari Browser on Windows?

Tags: windows, safari, screenshot

Is there a utility / plugin for Safari Web Browser on Window OS?  I want to capture a series of pages as PNGs.

If there is a way to create a script to do it, so it is repeatable, that would be ideal.

Comment: Can't you just use the print screen key?...

Comment: @BojinLi, He asked for an Utility or Plugin ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching, I've found extensions are avaialble for Safari at https://extensions.apple.com/.

Under the Photos category there is an extension called Awesome Screenshot.  This adds a little menu icon to take a shot of the whole page or the visible portion.  However, my pages are very large and it would cut-off the image.  Looks like a defect, and I couldn't find a way around it, so Awesome Screenshot wasn't useful for me.  I'm sure in most cases it would work fine.

There is also a Snapper extension, but it does not seem to have a way to capture the entire page, rather it only takes the visible portion.  There is also an Upshot extension, which integrates with http://upshotapp.com/, but this wasn't quite what I was looking for.

So after the extensions didn't work out for me, I found a nice little application to convert a Web page to PDF, http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/.  This worked very well, even though it create a PDF and not PNG I had hoped for, it was good enough for my purposes.  Furthermore, it has --page-width and --page-height options that allow creation of the PDF page at a custom size.  The running wkhtmltopdf --extended-help gives a more full explanation of all command line options.